# I have trouble combining :after and :nth-child in css

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I need two after elements with different hover effects. So, I tried using nth-child with after but my second after element is not showing up.

This is the code that I tried:

```css
.box {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background: #ff5733;
  transition: .5s;
}

.box:before {
  content: 'Java';
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background: #c70039;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: .5s;
}

.box:nth-child(1):after {
  content: 'Language';
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background: #900c3f;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: .5s;
}

.box:nth-child(2):after {
  content: 'Html';
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background: #581845;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: .5s;
}

.box:hover:before {
  opacity: 1;
  border-radius: 50%;
  transform: rotate(360deg);
}

.box:hover:nth-child(1):after {
  opacity: 1;
  border-radius: 50%;
  transform: translateX(100%) rotate(360deg);
}

.box:hover:nth-child(2):after {
  opacity: 1;
  border-radius: 50%;
  transform: translate(200%) rotate(360deg);
}

.box:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}

.box:hover:nth-child(1):after {
  opacity: 1;
  border-radius: 50%;
  transform: translateX(100%) rotate(360deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
```

I checked the syntax multiple times but couldn't find an error.

Comment: "I need two :after elements" you can't have two. Simple as that really.

Comment: but I've seen codes with two after elements.

Comment: I doubt it, since it's impossible.

Comment: at least describe the wanted result.

Comment: Perhaps trying to be more precise with your wording. Do you want 1 element with 2 `:after`'s (which is impossible), or do you want 2 elements with an `:after` on both?

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol answer in the answers section

Answer (score 1):

See what [the specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-pseudo-4/#treelike) says

> **::after**
>
> Represents a styleable child pseudo-element *immediately* after the originating element’s actual content.
>
> **::before**
>
> Represents a styleable child pseudo-element *immediately* before the originating element’s actual content.

Since you can select and style only the immediate children (which are `::before` and `::after`) of the originating element, having more than one `::after` element is not possible.